# Interface Error in pyodbc while connecting to database

Tags: python, sql-server, database-connection, pyodbc, pymssql

I am connecting to MSSQL Database. I am getting an error as the username contains "" I think this "" is giving the error.

In the following, I will attach my code and the error that I am getting. it would be good if someone can suggest some solution to this. As I already know there are two types of Authentication like Windows and the normal one. As I am trying to connect with the normal one. As I do have tried with the Windows one but it also didn't work out.
**NOTE:** I have tried with the commented connection string though but still not working. and you can see in the output that it is printing exactly what we want but when passing in the connect() function it's throwing an error.

Following is the code:

```
server = 'servername'
database = 'databasename'
username =  dict_config['username'] #"LOCAL\shahrukhan"
print(username)
password = password_asdfsd

# conn_str = r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password
# print(conn_str)
# mssql_db_conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
# mssql_db_conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password)
# mssql_db_conn = pyodbc.connect(Trusted_Connection=True, driver = '{SQL Server}',server = server, database = database)
mssql_db_conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                               'Server=servername;'
                               'Database=databasename;'
                               'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
# mssql_db_conn = pyodbc.connect(Trusted_Connection='no',Driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',Server=server,Database=database)
if(mssql_db_conn !=""):
    mssql_db_cursor = mssql_db_conn.cursor()
    print("Connected")
```

I am getting the following output:

````
LOCAL\\shahrukhan
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=servername;DATABASE=databasename;UID=LOCAL\\shahrukhan;PWD=password 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 34, in <module>
    mssql_db_conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'LOCAL\\shahrukhan'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'LOCAL\\shahrukhan'. (18456)") ```
````

Comment: Are you using SQL Authentication or Windows Authentication?

Comment: Windows Authentication, but I already tried windows auth bypassing windows connection string and still it didn't work out

Comment: Looks like this user doesn't have permissions maybe? Is it a `sysadmin` role? If not, have you assigned `CONNECT SQL` rights? Windows Authentication does not use passwords, just set `Trusted_Connection=yes;`